# Как хранить/работать с массивом параметров c отдельного файла?

Tags: c, массивы, файлы, global-variables

В ***Param.c*** файле хранится несколько глобальных массивов для хранения и взаимодействия с рядом параметров.
Для работы с ними я применил ***extern*** массивов в нужных файлах, однако предупреждение в ***Param.c*** не исчезло.

> 'Param..' defined but not used

Если же убрать ***extern***-ы и добавить ***static*** к массивам, то на консоль будет выводится нулевые значения массивов. ОДНАКО, принимающая параметры программа MissionPlanner отобразит все параметры корректно! Подскажите, как исправить ситуацию.

Схематический код:

```
|
|_main.h
| |_main.c
|
|_Params.c
|
|_Func.h
  |_Func.c

-------<main.c>-------
#include"main.h"
#include"Params.c"

extern float ParamValue[];

int main(..){
    GetVal();
    while(1){
        Print(ParamValue[PARAM_4]); //Custom debug print to UART(FTDI)
        SendVal(ParamValue[PARAM_4]);
    }
}

------<Params.c>------
enum ParamID{   PARAM_1=0,
                PARAM_2=1,
                PARAM_3,
                PARAM_4,
                PARAM_END};
float ParamValue[] = {  1.0f,
                        2.0f,
                        3.0f,
                        0.0f};

-------<Func.h>-------
#include "main.h"

void GetVal();
void SendVal(const float _param);

-------<Func.c>-------
#include"Func.h"
#include"Params.c"

extern float ParamValue[];

void GetVal(){
    ParamValue[PARAM_4] = 4.0f; 
}
void SendVal(const float _param){
    //Send via UART to MissionPlanner
}
```

ПС: знаю, использовать глобальные переменные в нескольких файлах дело опасное. Но я не придумал альтернативное хранение параметров. Если у кого-то будет совет - буду рад услышать!

Comment: `#include"Params.c"` - Это действительно то, что вы хотите?

Comment: @AlexF, уточните. Хочу ли я иметь все параметры в одном месте - да. Если есть другой подход, к которому я не додумался, буду рад помощи.

Comment: Файлы `.c` не включаются в другие файлы, а компилируются отдельно. Вы его используете как `.h` Уберите строки `#include"Params.c"` и перекомпилируйте проект - что получится?

Comment: Благодарю, @AlexF. Ошибка решилась. Жаль конечная цель осталась прежней (вывод на консоль остался прежним). Не могли бы посоветовать альтернативный способ хранения параметров?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Param.h:

```
#pragma once

enum ParamID{   PARAM_1=0,
                PARAM_2=1,
                PARAM_3,
                PARAM_4,
                PARAM_END};

extern float ParamValue[];
```

Param.c:

```
#include "Param.h"

float ParamValue[] = {  1.0f,
                        2.0f,
                        3.0f,
                        0.0f};
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Param.h"

int main()
{
    printf("%f", ParamValue[PARAM_3]);
    return 0;
}
```

Печатает:

`3.000000`

Теперь можете добавить к проекту `.c` файлы, в любом из них используйте `ParamID` и `ParamValue` как в `main.c`